# Delphi OpenTools API get component property

Tags: delphi, delphi-ide, opentools

I'm implementing a package to convert and auto-generate components in the delphi IDE. I'm aware that GExperts has a similar function but I need to customize some specific properties.

Right now I'm stuck on accessing the `TADOQuery.SQL` property, which is an instance of **TStrings**:

```
var
    aVal : TValue;
    aSqlS : TStrings;
begin
    [...]
    if (mycomp.GetComponentType = 'TADOQuery') then
        if mycomp.GetPropValueByName('SQL', aVal) then
        begin
            aSqlS := TStrings(aVal.AsClass);
            if Assigned(aSqlS) then             <----- problem is here
                ShowMessage(aSqlS.Text);        <----- problem is here
        end;
end;
```

I'm not really sure whether using **TValue** from RTTI is the correct way to go.

Thanks

Comment: IIRC, `aVal` should be of type `IOTAComponent` or `TIComponentInterface`. It depends on the type of `mycomp`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `GetPropValueByName()` is returning a valid `TValue` (you did not show that code), then using `aVal.AsClass` is wrong since the `SQL` property getter does not return a metaclass type.  It returns an object pointer, so use `aVal.AsObject` instead, or even `aVal.AsType<TStrings>`.

---

**Update** If `comp` is actually `IOTAComponent` than `TValue` is definitely wrong to use at all.  The output of `IOTAComponent.GetPropValueByName()` is an untyped `var` that receives the raw data of the property value, or an `IOTAComponent` for `TPersistent`-derived objects:

```
var
  aVal: IOTAComponent;
  aSqlS : TStrings;
begin
    [...]
    if (mycomp.GetComponentType = 'TADOQuery') then
      if mycomp.PropValueByName('SQL', aVal) then
        ShowMessage(TStrings(aVal.GetComponentHandle).Text);
end;
```

However, a better option would be to access the actual `TADOQuery` object instead:

```
if (mycomp.GetComponentType = 'TADOQuery') then
  ShowMessage(TADOQuery(comp.GetComponentHandle).SQL.Text);
```